# How to test a controlled input (via Redux state) that dispatches an action on its onChange handler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is my component:

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { Input } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ACTION } from "../../redux/appSlice";
import { RootState } from "../../redux/store";

interface IAddTodoForm {}

const AddTodoForm: React.FC<IAddTodoForm> = (props) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { addTodoForm } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.app);
  const { title } = addTodoForm;
  
  const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const title = e.target.value;
    dispatch(ACTION.UPDATE_TODO_INPUT({title}));
  };

  return(
    <Input 
      value={title} 
      onChange={onChange} 
    />
  );
};

export default React.memo(AddTodoForm);
```

It's a basic input that dispatches to Redux from the `onChange` handler.

This is what I'd like to test:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "../../../test/test-utils";
import AddTodoForm from "../AddTodoForm";

beforeEach(() => {
  render(<AddTodoForm/>);      // NOTE: THIS IS A CUSTOM render FUNCTION THAT ALREADY WRAPPED WITH THE <Provider store={store}> FROM react-redux
});

test("AddTodoForm updated input vale", () => {
  const { container } = render(<AddTodoForm/>);
  const input = container.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "NEW TODO" }});

  // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHECK IF THE INPUT VALUE HAS BEEN UPDATE
  // HOW CAN I DO THAT

});
```

As you can see, I would like to fire a `change` event, that should dispatch to the Redux store, and then I would like to confirm that the input has been updated with the `NEW TODO` value. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Note that's a misuse of aria-label, which should be _human readable_ as it will be read out to the user: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You would simply use an `expect` like so:**

```
test("AddTodoForm updated input vale", () => {
  const input = screen.getByLabelText("add-todo-input");
  expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "NEW TODO" }});

  expect(input.value).toBe('NEW TODO')
});
```

For an async operation, you could use this method instead:

```
await screen.findByText("NEW TODO");

expect(getByText("NEW TODO")).toBeTruthy();
```

By using `await findByText` you wait for the text to appear.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. That actually works. I expecting it to be more complicated than that.

Comment: Yeah. For an async operation, it actually a bit more complicated than that. Happy to help!

Comment: What would you use to wait for a `thunk` dispatch? Have you got any examples of that?

Comment: I added some details in the answer to answer your question, [Here](https://github.com/Ryan-LT/full-blown-react-structure) is a sample repository which I did a while ago, you can have a reference there.